# How to list PostgreSQL databases on server via JDBC driver?

Tags: list, postgresql, jdbc, database-schema

I have to make a graphical interface allowing the user to enter an IP / port (and ideally nothing else), and listing all the PostgreSQL databases found at this address.

The pg_hba.conf file on the server would be configured this way:

```
host    all    all    0.0.0.0/0    md5
```

Is there a way to list the databases without being connected to one of them?

If I set the server's config this way:

```
host    all    all    0.0.0.0/0    trust
```

I can connect to the postgres database with the postgres user, and list the databases, this way:

```
try (
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://<ip>:<port>/postgres", "postgres", null);
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
}
catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(System.err); }
```

But the trust option is really unsecured, can't use that. But there is no way to connect to that user with JDBC without giving him a password, right?

Comment: Try to use this solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172219/how-to-list-all-databases-and-their-schemas-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

No way, as you said: you can't query any database (and listing databases *is* a kind of query) without *connecting* to it first.

Hopefully, PostgreSQL has a built-in security system in `pg_hba.conf` as you saw. You'll have to tune it (on top of your firewall) to allow only:

- specific IPs
- and/or specific users
- with specific authentication mechanisms

Note that PostgreSQL handles SSL so you can trust its connections as much as you can trust any e.g. HTTPS.

See [current documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for more information.